# How to filter list by list element

Tags: c#, linq, list

For example, i have list

```
Rating rate1 = new Rating { artistID = 1, userID = 101, rating = 2 };
Rating rate2 = new Rating { artistID = 1, userID = 102, rating = 4 };
Rating rate3 = new Rating { artistID = 2, userID = 101, rating = 3 };
Rating rate4 = new Rating { artistID = 2, userID = 102, rating = 5 };
Rating rate5 = new Rating { artistID = 2, userID = 103, rating = 1 };
Rating rate6 = new Rating { artistID = 3, userID = 102, rating = 1 };
Rating rate7 = new Rating { artistID = 3, userID = 103, rating = 1 };

List<Rating> ratings = new List<Rating>(7);
ratings.Add(rate1);
ratings.Add(rate2);
ratings.Add(rate3);
ratings.Add(rate4);
ratings.Add(rate5);
ratings.Add(rate6);
ratings.Add(rate7);
```

And I Have second list,

```
List<Rating> ratings2 = new List<Rating>(2);
ratings2.Add(rate1);
ratings2.Add(rate3);
```

Now I want to filter `List<Rating> ratings` with `List<Rating> ratings2`.

In this cace, we use `artistID` element to filter list of ratings, in the other word i want to include all list that contain `artistID` **1 AND 2** which listed in ratings2

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If you are only going to compare `artistID` then you can do:

```
List<Rating> resultList = ratings.Where(r => ratings2.Select(t => t.artistID)
                                             .Contains(r.artistID))
                                             .ToList();
```

The above will select `artistIDs` for second list `ratings2` do a comparison similar to `SELECT * from Table WHERE ID IN (1,2)`

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `HashSet<int>` as fast lookup:

```
var r2Artists = new HashSet<int>(ratings2.Select(r2 => r2.artistID));
var result = ratings.Where(r => r2Artists.Contains(r.artistID));
```

Comment: The `Join` should be a `GroupJoin` to avoid potentially repeating items.

Comment: You don't need the `group by`, just the `into`.  That will perform a `GroupJoin` rather than a `Join` followed by a `GroupBy`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the possible duplicate issue with join, i have removed the join approach completely, i prefer the HashSet.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thx for solution, but i desired to get 1 more filter for rate5 which shouldn't be shown. If u can see the pattern. R1 =get list which userID 101 from `ratings`, then the result is = get list from `ratings` which have `userID 101` and `artistID` that also have `userID 101` (1 and 2, but rate5 not included because rate5 having userID 103).